# Why Mouse enter event fires mouse leave even arrow is still in top of element?

Tags: wpf, combobox, mouseevent

I have combo box with MouseEnter and MouseLeave events. When mouse enters to combobox, it should and does fires mouseEnter event. Setting its opacity to 100% from 40%. MouseLeave event does the other way around. Problem here is that when mouse enter, it fires mouse enter event and after that mouse leave event and mouse enter event again. Combobox will be stucked to opacity of 100%. How I can make this correct?

```
<ComboBox Name="PageNumberComboBox" Panel.ZIndex="10" Width="70" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,10,10,0" IsEditable="True" Opacity="0.4" MouseEnter="PageNumberComboBox_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="PageNumberComboBox_MouseLeave"></ComboBox>
```

Grid:

```
<Grid Panel.ZIndex="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
```

Code:

```
private void PageNumberComboBox_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PageNumberComboBox.Opacity = 100.0;
        MessageBox.Show("mouse enter");
    }

    private void PageNumberComboBox_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        PageNumberComboBox.Opacity = 40.0;
        MessageBox.Show("mouse leave");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <ComboBox>
        <ComboBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.4"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Style>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: whoah that worked thanks a lot!. Although Firinge event would be better option.